# How get params from link ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cookies, parameters, getparameter

I have column `inviter` in my User model. I want get params from the link and save it in cookies. For example, from this link:

```
domain.com/?ref=5
```

I want save to cookies number `?ref=**5**`

And when a user goes to registration, the user will not need to write in the number of the referral in the form, because it is already in cookies.

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
<%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

<%= f.label :name,'Your name'%>
<%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>

<%= f.label :email,'Email' %>
<%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>

<%= f.label :invite, 'Number who invited you' %>
<%= f.text_field :invite, class: 'form-control' %>

<%= f.label :password, 'password' %>
<%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %>

<%= f.label :password_confirmation ,'password confirmation' %>
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: 'form-control' %>
<br>
    <br>
    <div class="textc">
    <%= f.submit yield(:button_text), class: "formbut" %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

The invite number will use `?ref=**5**` and register the new user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add something like this to your `application_controller.rb`:

```
before_action :store_ref

private

def store_ref
  cookies[:ref] = params[:ref] if params[:ref].present?
end
```

And something like this to your user create action:

```
def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)
  @user.ref = cookies[:ref]

  if @user.save
  # ...
```

Comment: That method defintion looks pretty weird.

Comment: Ups, fixed it. Thanks

Comment: I got error "undefined method `before_filter' for ApplicationController:Class Did you mean? before_action"

Comment: I am sorry `before_filter` is deprecated. I fixed my answer. Use `before_action` instead.

Comment: Oh I got What I have to do . Just need change before_filter to before_action

Answer (score 0):

A better approach would be to use a hidden input and populate it with the value from `params[:ref]`.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new do |u|
      if params[:ref].present? 
        u.inviter = params[:ref]
      end
    end
  end

  # ...
end
```

---

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  # ...
  <% if f.object.inviter.present? %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :inviter %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

It requires less workarounds.

Comment: If `params[:ref]` is a user id you should also verify that the user actually exists.